# Adding custom classes required by maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I have an Ant task which is executed in maven by using `maven-antrun-plugin`. This tas uses an `XmlTask` to read some values from an XML file. The task fails with a class load error as the definition for this tas is in a separate jar. How can I add this jar to the classpath? I have tried adding this jar to the lib directory of both Maven and Ant, but still, I get this error.

Below is a section of my pom.xml where the error is:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>versionConsistency</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <target>
                <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
                <xmltask source="Upgrade.xml">
                    <copy path="component/versions/version/@number" property="fVer" />
                </xmltask>
                <property name="pVer" value = "${project.version}" />
                <script language="javascript">
                    <![CDATA[
                    fVer = project.getProperty('fVer');
                    pVer = project.getProperty('pVer');
                    if( fVer == pVer){
                        project.setProperty('isVerConsistent','true');
                    }else if (pVer.substring(0, pVer.search("-")) == fVer){
                        project.setProperty('isVerConsistent','true');
                    }else{
                        project.setProperty('isVerConsistent','false');
                        var fail = project.createTask("fail");
                        fail.setMessage("Project version and version in Upgrade.xml do not match");
                        fail.perform();

                    }
                ]]>
                </script>
            </target>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: You need to add it as a dependency in your pom http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-antrun-plugin-1.6/examples/customTasks.html

Comment: That said, I would recommend just using Ant's built-in `xmlproperty` task if possible, as well as Ant's `condition` task instead of that javascript block. It would make the code a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank you. Used Ant's `xmlproperty` tag. I have some more code in the script tag which can not be handled by Ant hence I moved the condition part also here.